# Subtraction of binary numbers with $1$’s complement

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, dynamical-systems

A digital calculating system uses $1$’s complement for its computation.
Illustrate how the calculating $d$ perform this operation. $$(10000)_2 – (11101)_2$$

Comment: You have now reproduced your task. Please correct my edits if necessary, for instance the solitary "$d$". Now you need to give some context on your view of that task, what you understand about it, how far you got, and what *your* question about it is. For instance, does the second term stand for $-2$ or for $-3$?

Comment: please it about number bases

Answer (score 0):

The **rules** of **subtraction using 1's complement** are as follows:

**1.** Obtain the **1's complement of the subtrahend** and then **add it to the minuend**.

**2. (a)** If the number **obtained in step 1**, **has an end carry** then **discard it** and **add the carry to the least significant digit of the result**.

**(b)** If the number **obtained in step 1**, **has no end carry** then **obtain 1's complement of the number obtained in step 1** and place **a negative sign before it**.

Now coming to your question,

```
Step -1:   minuend = (10000)2
           subtrahend = (11101)2 ----> 1's complement ----> (00010)2
           Binary Addition:  (10000)2 + (00010)2 = (10010)2
```

Here we don't have an end carry so by applying rule 2(b),

```
Step -2:  1's complement of the result of step -1, (10010)2 ---> (01101)2
          putting a negative sign before it we get, -(01101)2
```

So, the result is: **-(01101)2**